# Распознавание текста в большом количестве PDF документов

Tags: python, opencv, tesseract

Необходимо обработать 50 000 документов в формате pdf - вопрос извлечь из них текст?

PDF файлы хранят сканы каких-нибудь документов. То есть я понимаю алгоритм так:

1. Необходимо извлечь из pdf страницы, скорее всего в виде фотографий.
2. С помощью компьютерного зрения их распознать и извлечь из них текст.
3. Сформировать новый файл, который будет хранить этот самый текст.

Я думаю реализовать все это дело на Python.
Знаю о существующих библиотеках на нем OpenCV, Tesseract.
Но проблема в том, что распознавание одного документа идет слишком медленно.
Есть ли какой то способ быстро обработать большое количество документов, извлечь из них текст, причем возможны "помехи", то есть скан мог быть сделан не очень качественно. Возможно ли извлечь отдельно эти помехи, для дальнейшей обработки нейронной сетью?

Возможно вы сможете предложить принципиально другой подход для решения данной задачи.

Просто от размера в мб PDF файла зависит размер изображений, которые из него извлекаются и чем они больше, тем дольше tesseract их распознает.

Comment: А big data тут при чём? Ваши 50 000 документов занимают петабайт дискового пространства и каждый из них невозможно загрузить полностью в память?

Comment: Не петабайт конечно, но я думаю, что задача должна решаться с использованием многопоточности, а значит в на каждый поток придется выделить такое количество памяти, чтобы обработать каждое изображение извлеченное из pdf документов. Многопоточность для скорости само собой. Ну и соответственно чем больше изображение, тем больше памяти на него требуется. Ну а big data по сути все, что не может войти в оперативную память:) Прошу прощения, если я как то не так выразился

Comment: Ну и вообще да, при обработке 30 мб документа, генерировались изображения размером 500 мб, ну и если таких изображений 30, учитывая тот факт, как Python резервирует память... Да, скорее всего это big data

Comment: Это всё равно не big data. Big data - это тот объём данных, минимально неделимую порцию которого принципиально невозможно обработать одним узлом за разумное время или вообще за конечное. Образно говоря, если по вашему заказу IBM разрабатывает супер-компьютер за миллиарды долларов, а он не способен обработать данные быстрее, чем за год, то это  big data.

Comment: Соглашусь с вами, но все же, как мне решить мой вопрос?)

Comment: а вы на какой ОС, линукс, винда? Есть такая [штука](https://github.com/jbarlow83/OCRmyPDF)